# Android applications need WiFi but I have only ethernet connection

Tags: wi-fi

I have the Imito MX1 device that is working on Android 4.1. I have problem with WiFi quality (speed and reconnecting) so I use the Ethernet on the RJ45 to USB device. Unfortunately some of the applications that need Internet are not working. They are displaying communicate about lack of Internet. Is there any solution to redirect the ethernet to the WiFi device?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is a matter of permissions which are necessary for Ethernet but not for Wifi. Applications which do not work anymore might not have those permissions. Check them!

Comment: I am not sure about this but android applications have only permissions to access internet (there is no specification that internet should be accessed using wi-fi or ethernet)